# Developing web page with JSP (what to use instead of <table>)

Tags: jsp

I am a student.

I am developing my project with Netbeans 6.0.0 (JSP) using JSF. In my IADCS Project, my teacher said "Don't use label, Menu, and table". But all the reports must be generated in table.

I use static text instead of label and hyperlink for menu. But I don't know what to use instead of table.

Comment: And why does you teacher not want tables?

Comment: I guess you could use <pre> tags. And format your output as if you were printing columns to the console. Fixed width and all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<div>` tag and use `CSS` to style it. But `<table>` tag is there for a reason and should be used when required. Using `<div>` & `CSS` would be like a hack.

Anyways I found a good [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css) on this same issue, you can go through the first three answers with maximum votes and also the comments are worth reading to these answers and the question.

Answer (score 0):

this example page u can seet this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Admin Home</title>
<script>
function hide()
{
    var div_ref = document.getElementById("id_textbox_1");
    div_ref.style.visibility = "hidden";
}


function show()
{
    var div_ref = document.getElementById("id_textbox_1");
    div_ref.style.visibility = "visible";
}

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="if(history.length>0)history.go(+1)">
<%String user=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
String s3=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("change1");
String s4=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("update");
String s5=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("msg");
if(s5!=null)
{
    request.getSession().removeAttribute("msg");%>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    alert("Employee details deleted successfully");
</script>
<%}%>
<%if(s4!=null)
{
    request.getSession().removeAttribute("update");%>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    alert("Employee details updated successfully");
</script>
<%}%>
<%if(s3!=null)
{
    request.getSession().removeAttribute("change1");%>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    alert("The question for polling is set!!");
</script>
<%}%>
<%if(user==null)
{response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");}
    else{%>
<%@include file="headeradmin.jsp"%>
<div style="width:800px;height:22px;background-color:#708090;">

<form method="post" action="../SearchController"> 
<table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px"> 
<tr> 
<td style="border-style:solid none solid solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;">
<a href="emphome.jsp" style="color:white;text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="id" style="width:100px; border:0px solid; height:17px; padding:0px 3px; position:relative;"> 
</td>
<td style="border-style:solid;border-color:#4B7B9F;border-width:1px;"> 
<input type="submit" value="" style="border-style: none; background: url('../images/searchbutton3.gif') no-repeat; width: 24px; height: 20px;">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<font style="color:white;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 Welcome <label><%=user%></label></font> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="1"></input>
</form> </div>
<div style="height:550px; width:100%;float:left;margin-top:5px;">

<div align="justify" style="background-color:white; height:550px; width:74%;float:left;margin-top:5px; margin-left:10px">
<img src="../images/banner1.jpg" alt="emp1" height="180" width="590"></img><br>
<br><font size="4">Welcome</font><br>
<br><font size="2">
National Self Employment Program for Undergraduate
Students has come up with a unique solution that will encourage the family and
student to fund as much as they can and NSEP program to contribute the balance based on the
predefined condition.
Thanks for being a part of this prestigious initiative taken by NSEP to encourage under graduates in fulfilling
their dreams and stepping towards a bright future.</font><br>

<br><font size="2">"The spinning wheel means national consciousness and a contribution by every individual to definite 
constructive national work."
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

- M.K Gandhi</font><br>

<br></div>

<div style="background-color:white; height:550px; width:22%;float:left;margin-top:5px;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;">

<div style="background-color:white; height:25%; width:100%;float:left;margin-top:5px;margin-left:10px">
<p><br>"Education is the true alchemy that can bring India its next golden age.
Our motto is unambiguous:All for knowledge and knowledge for all."
<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-Shri Pranab Mukherjee.
<br></p>
</div>

<div style="background-color:white; height:25%; width:100%;float:left;margin-top:5px;margin-left:10px">
<p><br>"Everyone should find something they love doing. Then work isn't work. It's a part of themselves. Of who they are."
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-Paul Mcualay.
</p>
</div>

<div style="background-color:white; height:40%; width:100%;float:left;margin-top:5px;margin-left:10px">
<p><br>"At times our own light goes out and is rekindled by a spark from another person.  Each of us has cause to think with deep gratitude of those who have lighted the flame within us."  
<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;-Albert Schweitzer.
</p>
</div>
</div>
<%} %>
<%@include file="footeradmin.jsp"%>
 <center>
 <br><a href="nsephome_spn.jsp"><font color="white" >Spanish</font></a></br>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the CSS file I used for above page style1.css

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #333333;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}
table.linkcontainer td{
    background-color: #000000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: .7;
    -moz-opacity: .7;
}
td.logo_area{
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 5px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-right-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-left-color: #FFFFFF;
}
td.middle_spacer {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #666666;
}
td.shadow_right {
    background-image: url(../images_template1/border_shadow_l.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: left;
}
td.shadow_left {
    background-image: url(../images_template1/border_shadow_r.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: right;
}
td.body_content {
    padding: 5px;
    background-image: url(../images_template1/bg_content.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
td.below_header{
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    height: 50px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 5px;
}
td.main_content_box {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

td.horizontal_column {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-top-width: 15px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #000000;
    border-right-color: #000000;
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
    border-left-color: #000000;
    height: 150px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
td.bottom_link_container {
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
}

td.horizontal_center {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top-width: 15px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #000000;
    border-right-color: #333333;
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
    border-left-color: #333333;
    height: 290px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-image: url(../images_template1/header_bg.jpg);
}
td.header_column {
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: large;
    background-image: url(../images_template1/header2_bg.jpg);
    background-position: top;
}
td.left_content {
    width: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-image: url(../images_template1/bg_content.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

a.main_link:active,a.main_link:visited,a.main_link:link{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 50px;
}
a.main_link:hover{
    background-color:#333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a.bottom_link:active,a.bottom_link:visited,a.bottom_link:link{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
a.bottom_link:hover{
    color: #CCCCCC;
}
div.bottom_content{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
}
div.navigation {
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```