# Creating a 'Table' from divs in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have content in a 400px wide div that I would like repeated across the width of the screen with 30px spacing in between, similar to the layout of [these](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/) blog modules.

The number of modules per row would depend on the width of the screen, like in the above example.

I am new to creating this kind of layout using divs. My biggest problem is getting the divs to lie beside each other with 30px in between and then starting on a new line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css

Answer (score 1):

you can achive this by give `float` or `display:inline-block`

CSS:

```
.block {
    margin-right: 30px;
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height:500px
}

.block:nth-child(3n+3){margin-right:0}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block">...</div>
<div class="block">...</div>
<div class="block">...</div>
<div class="block">...</div>
<div class="block">...</div>
<div class="block">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
div.block {
    margin-right: 30px;
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block">...</div>
<div class="block">...</div>
<div class="block">...</div>
<div class="block">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. How do I go about adding the 30px in between the rows though?

Comment: add 'margin-bottom: 30px' to the css

Comment: Got it, thanks. one more thing to make my project perfect... is there a way to center all these divs on the screen, maybe by including them inside another div?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS :

```
.myclass {  
    margin-right: 30px;  
    float: left;  
    width: 400px;  
}
```

and HTML :

```
    <div>
         <div class="myclass">this is test block</div>
         <div class="myclass">this is test block</div>
         <div class="myclass">this is test block</div>
         <div class="myclass">this is test block</div>
   </div>
```