# Create Table using DIV's

Tags: html, css

I want to make a scalable 100% table using DIV's only. I don't want to use to display:table or display: table-cell since this doesnt work with IE7. The goal is to make this as cross browser compliant as possible.

```
<div class="Wrapper">
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">1</div>
        <div class="Cell">2</div>
        <div class="Cell">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">4</div>
        <div class="Cell">5</div>
        <div class="Cell">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If it's possible, I would like to make the cell width auto so if I add in more cells, it would fit into the row perfectly without pushing the cell to a second row. Been trying to figure this out. Any help would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: If this is tabular data, why not use a table?

Comment: Not to second-guess your question, but why are you trying to make a table out of `<div>`s? Could you not use a `<table>`?

Comment: I want to move completely away from tables if possible

Comment: Joe, tables are bad for layout, but not for, well, *tables*. Trying to emulate one with `<div>`s is a horrible, doomed effort.

Comment: Table are bad WHEN USED TO MAKE LAYOUTS. If it's a grid of logically-associated DATA then a table is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @Joe: why do you want to move completely away from tables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How create table only using <div> tag and Css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css)

Comment: @Paul - Div's seem cleaner and lightweight that's all. Just wondering if there was a scalable work around rather than using <table>

Comment: Choosing layout elements isn't religion. Displaying tabular data with div is just as bad as squeezing the whole page in a table. Wait for your first user asking: "IE always offered me to copy this table to Excel. Why doesn't this work any more?".

Comment: @Joe: I’m not sure what you mean by “cleaner”. What data are you looking to mark up? What layout are you trying to achieve? In short: what’s the context?

Comment: IE7 is down to like 3% market-share, do you really want to pull your hair out for a few weirdos who don't update their software? they get what they deserve.

Comment: @Paul - I'm outputting data records from the DB. I'm using a lot of jQuery in the site structure and the ultimate goal is to create a completely seemless css/div site.

Comment: @JKirchartz - Unfortunately, I work with nothing more than marketers and sales people lol

Comment: @Joe: “data records from the DB“ doesn’t really describe much. HTML is meant to convey meaning — `<p>` tags for paragraphs, `<section>` tags for sections, and so on. You’re not meant to use `<div>`s for everything.

Answer (score 3):

You can give your cells a width of 100/amount of cells %.
But if you want it automatically adjusted to the number of cells you will need javascript.

But I can't really get what advantage you see making a table out of divs.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a nice idea to...reinvent tables (what about header, footer and groups?). You may use 100% width (so it'll works with 90% of browsers) and conditional include for IE7, patching them with a CSS workaround (anchors?) for that people that are still using IE7.

Comment: Its not about reinventing anything. Admit it html tables suckss. They don't even have a scroll on tbody.

Comment: @ArunAravind I admit...they're not best tool we can imagine to use to display data! You may (more or less) Always get behavior you need but you Always need JS and tricks. Annoying.

Comment: Yeah i agree, but it won't hurt to have the component under over control and you don't need any complex script to maintain it. pretty simple thing.

Comment: @ArunAravind IMO it depends what you have to do. For example if, as you pointed out, you don't have to scroll body then I can't imagine a situation where I would reinvent table. First of all because (if it's not just an exercise) you'll need to implement a lot of things; second because you won't add anything more than a table+css+javascript (with cost of a lot of browser differences to handle)

Comment: Tables are good, bur for static data or for a limited amount of data. What if you want to render 1000 rows of data and virtualize the table.

Comment: @ArunAravind I would keep the table as is and I'll paginate its data with AJAX. I don't think to re-implement them using divs may help in this.

Comment: I dont want to overload the server. You can push all the processing to the front end. by this i don't mean i would flush all the data to the client. Server side evaluation is ok, in case the requests are not frequent.

Comment: @ArunAravind again I think it depends on specific scenario. Client side pagination can be OK for few hundreds of items (or much much less) but I would avoid it if (let's say) more than 40/50 (both because of bandwidth and javascript pagination speed). Server may be less loaded with more small requests than with few very big ones.

Comment: Anyway even if you leave front-end in charge of everything...there will be tables there. I mean: wherever you do it...it's not a reason to avoid tables in favor of a custom implementation (unless your table is too far away from... a table and it's like a grid with groups, editing, regions and stuff like that).

Comment: I din't mean there is a need to reinvent tables. Afterall the table API is soo poor that you cannot even make them look the way you want. Cannot set height, and lot other. Current tables are not suited for present day "Big data analysis" works. Moreover each browser renders tables in its own way. Obviously, if you don't want it to be dynamic, tables can be used. but not if you want to modify the contents on the go or even style them

Answer (score 1):

Something like: 
http://linuxandfriends.com/2009/04/04/how-to-style-div-elements-as-tables/
But what for?

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this as, even for tabular data, I wanted to challenge myself to present it using `ul` and `li`. You can emulate `ul` and `li` to act as your rows and columns.

Consider the following:

```
<ul id="column-one">
  <li>Cell #1</li>
  <li>Cell #2</li>
  <li>Cell #3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="column-two">
  <li>Cell #1</li>
  <li>Cell #2</li>
  <li>Cell #3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { list-style: none; }
  ul li { height: 20px; }
#column-one,
#column-two {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
```

If you need to emulate `colspan`:

```
.span-4 {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; /* if you have 4 UL elements */
}
```

You'll run into issues if the height of your cells is different. You could create "rowspan" classes which would increase the `height`.

It's totally up to you. I have always been a proponent for displaying tabular data **within** a `<table>`, but if you want to challenge yourself, please do so!

Comment: Do I have to define the width of each cell or can I some how use width:auto? It makes it challenging when I have an odd number of cells in a 100% width table

Comment: Your `li` will inherit the width of the `ul`.