# How to use Div tag instead of table

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How create table only using <div> tag and Css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css)

I have a table which contains 1000 records in my jsp page. When performing tab/input operations in IE-8, there is a slow response from browser. Due to which I would like to change all the table tags with div tag which might speed up the response.

How to change to div tags for below table code in html.

```
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 240px;">
                <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=2 CELLPADDING=2 WIDTH="100%">
                    <TR>
                        <TD ALIGN="CENTER">
                            <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=2 CELLPADDING=2>
                                <TR>
                                    <TH ALIGN="left" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20" BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0">
                                        <B>AAAAA</B>
                                    </TH>
                                    <TH ALIGN="left" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20" BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0">
                                        <B>BBBBBB</B>
                                    </TH>
                                    <TH ALIGN="left" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20" BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0">
                                        <B>CCCCC</B>
                                    </TH>
                                    <TH ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20" BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0">
                                        <B>DDDDDD</B>
                                    </TH>
                                    <TH ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20" BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0">
                                        <B>EEEEEEE</B>
                                    </TH>
                                    <TH ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20" BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0">
                                        <B>${aaaaa}</B>
                                    </TH>
                                    <TH ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20" BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0">
                                        <B>${bbbbb}</B>
                                    </TH>
                                    <TH ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20" BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0">
                                        <B>Next</B>
                                    </TH>
                                    <TH ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20" BGCOLOR="#C0C0C0">
                                        <B>Ready</B>
                                    </TH>
                                </TR>

                                <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item" varStatus="status">                              
                                    <TR>
                                        <TD ALIGN="right" width=120 VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20">
                                            ${aaaaa}
                                        </TD>
                                        <TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20">
                                            ${bbbbbb}
                                        </TD>
                                        <TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20">
                                            ${cccccc}
                                        </TD>
                                        <TD BGCOLOR="gray" ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20">
                                            <input type="text" NAME="total" SIZE="7" MAXLENGTH="7"
                                                VALUE="0">
                                        </TD>
                                        <TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20">
                                            <input type="text" NAME="tbHd" SIZE="7"
                                                MAXLENGTH="7" VALUE="0">
                                        </TD>
                                        <TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20">
                                            <input type="text" NAME="tbHd" SIZE="7"
                                                MAXLENGTH="7" VALUE="0">
                                        </TD>
                                        <TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20">
                                            <input type="text" NAME="tbHd" SIZE="7"
                                                MAXLENGTH="7" VALUE="0">
                                        </TD>
                                        <TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20">
                                            <input type="text" NAME="tbHd" SIZE="7"
                                                MAXLENGTH="7" VALUE="0">
                                        </TD>
                                        <TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20">
                                            <input type="text" NAME="tbHd" SIZE="7"
                                                MAXLENGTH="7" VALUE="0">
                                        </TD>
                                    </TR>

                                </c:forEach>
                                <TR>
                                    <TD></TD>
                                    <TD></TD>
                                    <TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20">
                                        <B>Total:</B>
                                    </TD>
                                    <TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN=MIDDLE HEIGHT="20">
                                        <input type="text" NAME="tbTotal" SIZE="7"
                                            MAXLENGTH="7" VALUE="0">
                                    </TD>
                                    <TD></TD>
                                    <TD></TD>
                                    <TD></TD>
                                    <TD></TD>
                                    <TD></TD>
                                    <TD></TD>
                                    <TD></TD>
                                    <TD></TD>
                                </TR>

                            </TABLE>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css

Comment: I think that would take a lot of CSS to acomplish and would be evil,  anyway here is the JSbin -> http://jsbin.com/aveban/1/edit

Comment: Tables are for data, keep using a table.

Comment: @Andy using tables in IE-8 browser have very slow response when we perform input/tab operation on it. Due to that only I want to change to div tags.

Comment: @Ran maybe make the decision not to support IE8? Tabular data should always be in tables. No matter what occasion.

Comment: Agreeing with @Rune here. I don't know that replacing a table with a div is going to gain you anything. Especially if what you are presenting is tabular data and there is no indication of what the data is. It might be that what you are presenting just takes a long time to render.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the way you will treat/style the `div`s, your page will not necessarily render faster, and it appears it will make it less semantic and accessible. Instead, you might want to try adding the following rule to your stylesheet:

```
table { table-layout: fixed }
```

It has some disadvantages, but it will probably render a lot faster. (Also, you would run into the same disadvantages when using `div`s; again, depending on the way you treat/style them.)

Comment: This should be the first approach, when it comes to slow rendering times.

Comment: I already did this, but still I see slow response.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS proprites display:table and display:table-row and display:table-column to style your div tags and tweak them to appear like a table

however check out this post, it has an example
[How create table only using <div> tag and Css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div style="float: left; width: 30px; height: 100%; background-color: green;">left</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 30px; height: 100%; background-color: blue;">right</div>
<div style="margin-left: 30px; margin-right: 30px; height: 100%; background-color: yellow;">Content!...</div>​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/DrFhT/