# Create table using div and CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have div tags in below format:

```
<div>first</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>last</div>
```

I want it in 2X3(col X row) table. Is it possible? Only using CSS without adding any other HTML tag.
If Yes, then what would be the CSS for that?

Output format:
first
1   4
2  5
3  6
 Last

I want data in above format.
Sorry I did not mention the format in above question.

Comment: If you need a tabular format, use a table.

Comment: @Oded Exactly that. I really don't understand why people object to `<table>` so much...

Comment: @Kolink - It used to be used for layout before CSS existed and became popular, so it became a "code smell" and the mantra was that one should be using `div`s for layout and not tables. Some people take that to mean that tables shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: @Odey and Kolink..i am NOT creating above HTML.It is self generated by some plugin in my code. So i can't change that HTML but i can add some CSS classes to them.Thats why i needed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this css:

```
.div-table{
  display:table;         
  width:auto;         
  background-color:#eee;         
  border:1px solid  #666666;         
  border-spacing:5px;/*cellspacing:poor IE support for  this*/
}
.div-table-row{
  display:table-row;
  width:auto;
  clear:both;
}
.div-table-col{
  float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
  display:table-column;         
  width:200px;         
  background-color:#ccc;  
}
```

Comment: I've seen this answer being copied from one thread to another. However there are 2 issues with it. The "float:left" will make the cells wrap when the table doesn't fit on the screen. The entire table will look like a jigsaw puzzle. Secondly, I think it makes more sense to use: `display:table-cell` which mimics the `<td>` element. The `table-column` option mimics a `<col>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
    ​div {
        float:left;
        width: 50%;
    }​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/LUMg2/

A context is needed to make sure it really works in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for such a simple answer..i am taking it.Thanks a Lot.You saved my day

Comment: I want above format..i tried to tweak your CSS but it didn't work

Comment: As I said, it depends on the scenario.  Many problems can occur for example :
1. The content could be longer than 50%.
2. Your divs could have other styles applied.

Edit: I just saw that you updated your question.  You can check that example.
http://jsfiddle.net/LUMg2/1/

Again, if other styles are applied, you need to overwrite them.

Answer (score 0):

Use **display:table-row;** You might find the following links helpful.

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di

There are several previous discussions on this.

[How create table only using <div> tag and Css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css)

Ultimately, if you want a real table, just use the `table` tag.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me Unor.

Answer (score 0):

There are easy solutions for this:

```
div {widht:50%;flot:left;padding:none;position:relative}
```

But if you want to show tabular data, use `table`, that what a table is for.
If you want to layout something, don't use a table.

Maybe a definition List would do the job for you:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

dl, dt, dd

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#board
{
    margin:100px 100px 100px 400px;
}
#r1,#r2,#r3
{
   display:table-row;
   width:auto;
   text-align:center;
   background-color:White;
}
#r1c1,#r1c2,#r1c3,#r2c1,#r2c2,#r2c3,#r3c1,#r3c2,#r3c3
{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-column;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:solid 1px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    font-size:larger;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="board">

<div id="r1">
    <div id="r1c1"></div>
    <div id="r1c2"></div>

</div>
<div id="r2">
    <div id="r2c1"></div>
    <div id="r2c2"></div>
</div>
<div id="r3">
    <div id="r3c1"></div>
    <div id="r3c2"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```