# How to correctly use tableless layout with borders using CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, doctype

I'm working on a new HTML page and I want to use a table-less layout.  Bear in mind that what follows here is only part of the page, but I think it paints a clear picture of what I'm trying to do.

The HTML below is meant to render six cells with text inside.  I want the cells to be sized appropriately to contain the text inside.

The problem I'm having is that the borders are drawn incorrectly.  In both IE and Firefox, I see two problems:

1) One of the borders is drawn outside the table.

2) The borders between the cells in the first row are drawn incompletely.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

html
{
}
.reviewRow 
{    
    clear:both;    
}
.reviewBlock 
{
 float:left; 
 border-top: 1px solid #444; 
 border-left: 1px solid #444;
}
.rightBorder
{
    border-right: 1px solid #444;
}
.bottomBorder
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;   
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class='reviewRow'>
    <div style="width:200px;" class='reviewBlock'>      
        THIS TEXT IS MUCH LONGER THAN THE TEXT IN THE OTHER CELLS
    </div>
    <div style="width: 225px" class='reviewBlock'>      
        ABC
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100px" class="reviewBlock rightBorder">      
        December 25, 2012
    </div>
</div>
<div class='reviewRow bottomBorder'>
    <div style="width:300px;" class='reviewBlock'>      
        Hello, World!
    </div>
    <div style="width: 125px" class='reviewBlock'>      
        123
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100px" class="reviewBlock rightBorder">      
        May 1, 2013
    </div>
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use a table? Tables are absolutely fine for a table of data... they were made for your purpose

Comment: One particular reason not to use them here is that I don't want the data to be displayed in a grid where each row has the same number (and layout) of cells.

I suppose I could use a different table for each row, but I've been given the impression that CSS is the preferred solution.  I could be wrong.  That's why I'm asking here :-)

Comment: For noobs who are not yet able to visualize HTML/CSS code on-the-fly, this is how it looks: http://jsfiddle.net/BK5Yq/1/ `:P`

Comment: @Andy Nested tables are difficult to style. For instance, how do you select the cells of the outer table with CSS selectors (without also selecting the inner cells)?

Comment: @Andy No, it doesn't. The browsers insert a TBODY element, so the selector would have to be `#table > tbody > tr > td`.

Comment: @Andy That was my point. The selector required to select the cells of the outer table is too long. That's one reason why I recommend *against* nested tables. The other reason is that the resulting structure is unnecessarily deep, e.g. TABLE > TBODY > TR > TD > TABLE > TBODY > TR > TD. This structure depth can be halved by using UL > LI > UL > LI.

Comment: The markup you choose should never be dictated by what it looks like.  Just like lists don't have to look like lists, tables don't have to look like tables.  This page has a table that's been completely restyled, can you find it?  http://gw.gamependium.com/tools/builds/show/68

Comment: @Andy OP can have two separate adjacent tables (as Mr. Alien shows in a comment to his answer). I don't see the need for the outer wrapper table.

Comment: @Andy You wrote "*Just use a table, nested tables whatever you need*". My point is that nested tables are not a good idea.

Comment: @Andy You suggested nested tables. I'm merely pointing out that I think that's not a good idea. Witch hunt? Relax, for the love of polar bears, I'm just making a valid point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't go what others say, that don't make layouts using tables, but when it comes to tabular data and if you use div's for making a table doesn't make any sense to me, just don't use tables for designing layouts, but YOU SHOULD USE IT FOR TABULAR DATA

Still if you want to use you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css)

Comment: Mr. Alien, I've followed your suggestion.  I've written the two rows as separate tables because they have different layout.  When I use `border-collapse`, everything is perfect except for one thing: there is a double-border between the two rows (since they are separate elements each with their own border).  I suppose I could omit the bottom border from the top row, but that's a bit ugly; can you recommend something better?

Comment: why two rows for separate layouts? use colspan and rowspans

Comment: Suppose, for the sake of discussion, that I want to do a table 600px wide.  The first row is to have three cells, each 200px wide, and the second row is to have two cells, each 300px wide.  I know of no way to do this without using separate `table` tags for each row.  If you know better, please enlighten me.

Comment: What you did is what I expected I would need: two table elements.  I thought you were saying I could do it (1 table, 3 fields, 2 fields) with a single table element.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon I didn't knew you had odd column widths :)

Comment: arguably, a table with one row with 3 columns followed by a second row of two columns is really not tabular data and is using a table for layout purposes.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, to answer the question... You can use [display:table, table-cell and table-row](http://ajaxian.com/archives/display-table) (in CSS3)

But I agree with Mr. Alien : just use tables for tabular data.

Answer (score 1):

See the height of html elements are computed based on the content inside them unless you explicitly specify it.

Your second div has taken only the height necessary to show **ABC** and hence the border showed up only that much. To fix this you must specify a certain height to each of the div so that they appear just as you want.

If you are trying to show data in a tabular manner just use tables. They are there for that purpose only. You can obviously style them in order to make them better looking.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this for tabular data, then by all means **use a table** that's what it's there for. Not doing so it about like trying to use Photoshop to make a spreadsheet when Excel would be the better tool.

You can change the number of columns a cell takes up by using the `colspan` attribute. By default, of course, a cell takes up 1 column (`colspan="1"`), but if you need it to take up more, you simply change the number. You  can do the same thing for rows with `rowspan`.