# Create three rows using div like table tr

Tags: css, html

I want to create simple three `div` rows (tableless concept).

I tried everything in Google but I didn't get a simple format.

For example in table it was so easy in this way:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Sorry if I'm asking a very simple question here.

Comment: `<div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do, is create one div, for which you create three child divs:

```
<div>
   <div>Content</div>
   <div>Content</div>
   <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

This should work with default styling, you will get rows of content. If you need any more help with specific styling, just comment.

Answer (score 8):

## HTML4 and HTML5 Methods

It's sometimes best to code elements as with little code as possible, below you can view ideal coding for Columns and Rows in HTML5 and HTML4 doctypes. It's important to note that HTML5 doesn't replace DIV but in my example it shows that sometimes you just don't need to use them if it means reducing your code.

## 3 Columns a simple HTML5 method without additional divs

**HTML5**

```
<article id="fruits">

    <hgroup>    
        <h1>Some of My Favorite Fruits</h1>
        <h2>I generally prefer fruits that are not to sweet</h2>
    </hgroup>

    <section>
        <h2>Bananas<h2>
        <p>Some Text..</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Kiwi<h2>
        <p>Some Text..</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Pears<h2>
        <p>Some Text..</p>
    </section>

</article>
```

**CSS**

```
#fruits section {width:100%;padding:20px 0;}
```

## 3 Columns using a simple HTML4 method with few classes

**HTML4**

```
<div class="3-columns">

    <div>I'm Column 1</div>

    <div>I'm Column 2</div>

    <div>I'm Column 3</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.3-columns {}
.3-columns div {width:100%;padding:20px 0;}
```

## 3 Rows using a simple HTML5 method without additional divs

**HTML5**

```
<article id="fruits">

    <hgroup>    
        <h1>Some of My Favorite Fruits</h1>
        <h2>I generally prefer fruits that are not to sweet</h2>
    </hgroup>

    <section>
        <h2>Bananas<h2>
        <p>Some Text..</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Kiwi<h2>
        <p>Some Text..</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Pears<h2>
        <p>Some Text..</p>
    </section>

    <div class="clear"> </div>

</article>
```

**CSS**

```
#fruits section {float:left;width:33.3%;}
.clear {clear:both;}
```

## 3 Rows using a simple HTML4 method with few classes

**HTML4**

```
<div class="3-rows">

    <div>I'm Row 1</div>

    <div>I'm Row 2</div>

    <div>I'm Row 3</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.3-rows {}
.3-rows div {width:33.3%;float:left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted previously on the site, you may want to use the table tag instead of divs for showing tabular data.

See [How create table only using <div> tag and Css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css)

Answer (score 1):

### 3 column in 1 row

```
<div>
   <div class="id">Stack</div>
   <div class="id">Overflow</div>
   <div class="id">Rulez</div>
</div>
```

And the style code:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
   .id {
      width:33%;
      float:left;
   }
</style>
```

### 3 row in 1 column

```
<div>
   <div>Stack</div>
   <div>Overflow</div>
   <div>Rulez</div>
</div>
```