# Height of table rows won't stay fixed

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating rows and cells into an HTML-table dynamically through javascript.

Here is as snippet:

```
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row1 = table.insertRow(rowCount);

var cell1_1 = row1.insertCell(0);
cell1_1.innerHTML = "From";
```

If my function adds 5 rows there is a lot of blank space between the rows. They are spread from the top of the page to the bottom. I've tried setting the style.height of the rows to 20 px zo stay fixed, but it doesn't work. I want a fixed height for each row.

Comment: add an `overflow: hidden` that should make them stay fixed

Comment: It turns out the CSS file had a fixed height for the table element. This was the problem. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You might use div tag instead of table. You get more information about div [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css)

**2.** You can apply style on "cell1_1" by using:

```
    cell1_1.style.height="20px";
```

But each brower have *calculated style* and *style based on rules*. So to "overload" these rules just use following:

```
    cell1_1.style.display="inline-block";
```

I hope it help !

**EDIT**
The result:

```
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row1 = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1_1 = row1.insertCell(0);
    cell1_1.innerHTML = "From";
    cell1_1.style.height="20px";
    cell1_1.style.display="inline-block";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### CSS

```
.testTable {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.testTable > tbody > tr {
    height:20px !important;
    vertical-align:middle !important;
}
.testTable > tbody > tr > td {
    height:20px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
// Assign a class to the table
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
table.className = 'testTable'
```