# Create table using div in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering how can I create a table using only divs in javascript? The code should include only one script, the body should be empty. Any help?

Comment: You can't create a table using divs in javascript. A table is a table. A div is a div. Do you mean how to layout div containers beside eachother?

Comment: No. I'm gonna have an exam in JS, and a teacher said we should practice a few things, and one the things was to create a table using divs. I have no idea what this means.

Comment: My guess is that he means to simply lay divs beside eachother (`float: left; width: 100px;`), but I don't know.

Comment: I guess, you are ask to create UI(user interface) using divs and  it looks like as it is created by table tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can only layout divs like a table, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css). There are css display property with possible values: `table`, `table-row`, `table-column`, `table-cell` ([More info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GeLt/)