# How to use CSS to create a matrix of cells, and not use HTML tags at all

Tags: css

I wish to create a matrix of cells with the names of people. I want to create a 3 by 3 matrix of names. So far I just have one row of names, but I want to add another two rows. I know I can do this using the HTML "tr" and "td" tags, but is there a way I can do this purely using CSS?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        body {background-color: lightgray}
        div {
            float:left;
            width: 300px;
            padding: 25px;
            border: 25px solid navy;
            margin: 25px;
            }

       </style>
       </head>
       <body>

       <div>James</div><div>Richard</div><div>Kevin</div>

       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: CSS is not designed to do such things. Generating contents can be done only by `::before`/`::after` pseudo-elements. However I doubt that it fits your needs.

Comment: Sure, using CSS features like `display: table;`, `display: table-cell`, etc. If you want to add more *content*, though, you'll need to add it to your HTML.

Comment: You do notice he is using div. SO HE WANTS TO STYLE DIVs TO LOOK LIKE A TABLE!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep using div elements and still achieve your 3x3 matrix by just wrapping every row with a div.

```css
.row{
  width: 390px;
}
.row div{
  float:left;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div>James</div>
    <div>Richard</div>
    <div>Kevin</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>James</div>
    <div>Richard</div>
    <div>Kevin</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>James</div>
    <div>Richard</div>
    <div>Kevin</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Escobear (any relation to Pablo Escobar?), I wish I could've given you a Vote Up, but I don't have enough Reputations (just joined two days ago), but I've accepted your answer. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Anyway, this is some basic html/css which could be solved by investing 5 minutes using the search engine of your choice or forum search.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `flexbox`:

```css
.flex {
  font: 14px Arial;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex > div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 33.3%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>James</div>
  <div>Richard</div>
  <div>Kevin</div>
  <div>James</div>
  <div>Richard</div>
  <div>Kevin</div>
</div>
```

#### [Nice Link to Learn](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) also check the [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 2):

CSS3 has `columns` property:

```css
.divTable
{
    -webkit-columns: 1px 3;
    -moz-columns: 1px 3;
    columns: 1px 3;
}
```

```html
<div class='divTable'>
    <div>James</div><div>Richard</div><div>Kevin</div>
    <div>James</div><div>Richard</div><div>Kevin</div>
    <div>James</div><div>Richard</div><div>Kevin</div>
</div>
```

It forms columns first and then rows (all Jameses will go to the first row). But it flexible with regards to the width.

Comment: Nadia, thank you for pointing me out to the columns property, which I have to read up on.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<style>
.main div {
    float:left;
    margin:3px;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.main div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear:left;
}
 </style>

<div class="main">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .Table
    {
        display: table;
    }
    .Title
    {
        display: table-caption;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    .Heading
    {
        display: table-row;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .Row
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Table">
    <div class="Title">
        <p>This is a Table</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Heading">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Heading 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Heading 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Heading 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 1 Column 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 1 Column 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 1 Column 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 2 Column 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 2 Column 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Row 2 Column 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```