# Table row outline: why are the left and top edges invisible if container div has overflow:auto style?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with table inside. Div should be scrollable in case if table gets large.
I try to make something like an active row in a table. If user clicks on a row, the row gets outlined.
The problem is that for the first row of the table the top edge of outline is not shown, and for the other rows the left edge of the outline is not shown.

Why does this happen and how to overcome it?

```js
$('tr').click(function(){
 $('tr').removeClass('row-outline');
  $(this).addClass('row-outline');
});
```

```css
.row-outline{
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; 
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  border-right: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 50px;">
  <table style="">
    <tr class="row-outline">
      <td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `outline` try `border`. Check below update.

```js
$('tr').click(function() {
  $('tr').removeClass('row-outline');
  $(this).addClass('row-outline');
});
```

```css
.row-outline {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 50px;">
  <table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr class="row-outline">
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>2.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td>3.2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: In the original question it helped, but the row height changed. I edited my example. The actual problem is that both table and cells have borders, and if I use border instead of outline, it's not visible at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies withing `border-collapse`

if you remove this tag the "row" gets its border properly but on the other hand the "table" border is still displayed at top and bottom so this might not be a very confincing solution

if you on the other hand simulate the table with divs you could deal with it more easily i guess:

Read more about it here:
[How create table only using <div> tag and Css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css)