# Using divs instead of tables tag to be responsive without bootstrap

Tags: html, css, css-tables, tabular

I'm trying to create the following table: but I need to use DIVs instead of tables. Structure I want to create:

[image]

I have to have 3 global Divs without using any table tag. I don't see how is it possible to do it without table tags, only divs here is what I tried [codepen link](https://codepen.io/ZinebS/pen/mwQVrW)

```css
.wrapTableTech {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14rem;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.blocTech {
  display: table-header-group;
  background-color: gray;
}

.tech-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2pxsolid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.blocCat {
  display: table-row-group;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.tech-row {
  display: table-row;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapTableTech">
  <div class="blocTech">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class="tech-cell">Tech 1</div>
    <div class="tech-cell">Tech 2</div>
    <div class="tech-cell">Tech 3</div>
    <div class="tech-cell">Tech 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocCat">
    <div class="tech-row">PTI</div>
    <div class="tech-row">HO</div>
    <div class="tech-row">OP</div>
    <div class="tech-row">AS</div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocValue">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>6 hours</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css) about creating a table with divs, hope it will help you.

Comment: use bootstrap grid system

Comment: May I ask *why* you can't use a `table`? Also, check out [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Comment: i'm using only native css...@domdom i want it to be responsive and flexible and also the possibility to control each bloc in small device..i this is how where i work want it to be

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How create table only using <div> tag and Css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css)

Comment: Zinebs, I fail to see how a `table` wouldn't be responsive or flexible enough; you could even hide/show individual cells, columns or rows. If you are dealing with tabular data, I suggest to use a `table`. But you are, obviously, free to ignore this advice and try one of the solutions provided in the answers here on in the linked duplicate question.

Comment: @domdom when you a complexe data table.. it's not always easy to make it responsive and control every bloc when it's table tag i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand that a div is a container.
Therefore, the structure must be hierarchical in order to solve this problem, but not separated into 3 different individual divs (=containers).

Try something like:

```css
  .wrapTableTech {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 14rem;
    border: 2px solid;
  }
  .blocTech {
    display: table-header-group;
    background-color: gray;

  }
  .tech-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    text-align:center;
  }
  .blocCat {
    display: table-row-group;
    background-color: gray;text-align: center;

  }
  .tech-row {
    display: table-row;
    border: 2px solid red;
  }

  .tech-RowTitle {
   display: table-cell;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    text-align:center;
  }

  .tech-value {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapTableTech">
  <div class="blocTech">
    <div class="tech-cell"></div>
    <div class="tech-cell">Tech 1</div>
    <div class="tech-cell">Tech 2</div>
    <div class="tech-cell">Tech 3</div>
    <div class="tech-cell">Tech 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocCat">
    <div class="tech-row"> 
      <div class="tech-RowTitle">PTI</div>
      <div class="tech-value">1.1</div>
      <div class="tech-value">1.2</div>
      <div class="tech-value">1.3</div>
      <div class="tech-value">1.4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tech-row">
       <div class="tech-RowTitle">HO</div>
       <div class="tech-value">2.1</div>
       <div class="tech-value">2.2</div>
       <div class="tech-value">2.3</div>
       <div class="tech-value">2.4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tech-row">
       <div class="tech-RowTitle">OP</div>
       <div class="tech-value">3.1</div>
       <div class="tech-value">3.2</div>
       <div class="tech-value">3.3</div>
       <div class="tech-value">3.4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tech-row">
       <div class="tech-RowTitle">AS</div>
       <div class="tech-value">4.1</div>
       <div class="tech-value">4.2</div>
       <div class="tech-value">4.3</div>
       <div class="tech-value">4.4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank's for your brief explanation... this is what i was looking for...to seperate each bloc

Answer (score 1):

Try below css and Html without bootstrap:

```css
.wrapTableTech {
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.blocTech {
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
.tech-cell {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;text-align:center;
}
.blocCat {
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
.tech-row {
    border: 2px solid green;
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapTableTech">
  <div class="blocTech">
    <div class="tech-cell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="tech-cell">PTI</div>
    <div class="tech-cell">HO</div>
    <div class="tech-cell">OP</div>
    <div class="tech-cell">AS</div>
  </div>
  <div class="blocCat">
    <div class="blocvalue">
      <div class="tech-row">Tech 1</div>
      <div class="tech-row">Tech 2</div>
      <div class="tech-row">Tech 3</div>
      <div class="tech-row">Tech 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocvalue">
      <div class="tech-row">1</div>
      <div class="tech-row">4</div>
      <div class="tech-row">6 Hours</div>
      <div class="tech-row">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocvalue">
      <div class="tech-row">2</div>
      <div class="tech-row">5</div>
      <div class="tech-row">3 Hours</div>
      <div class="tech-row">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocvalue">
      <div class="tech-row">1</div>
      <div class="tech-row">4</div>
      <div class="tech-row">6 Hours</div>
      <div class="tech-row">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="blocvalue">
      <div class="tech-row">2</div>
      <div class="tech-row">5</div>
      <div class="tech-row">3 Hours</div>
      <div class="tech-row">5</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapTableTech {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14rem;
  border: 2px solid;
}
.blocTech {
  display: table-header-group;
  background-color: gray;

}
.tech-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;text-align:center;
}
.blocCat {
  display: table-row-group;
  background-color: gray;text-align: center;
  
}
.tech-row {
  display: table-row;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
    <div class=" row wrapTableTech">
      <div class="blocTech">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 tech-cell">Tech 1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 tech-cell">Tech 2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 tech-cell">Tech 3</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 tech-cell">Tech 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blocCat">
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell">PTI</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
      </div>
     <div class="blocCat">
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell">HO</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
      </div>
       <div class="blocCat">
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell">OP</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
      </div>
       <div class="blocCat">
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell">AS</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 blocValue tech-cell"><input type="text"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank's  but this is with bootstrap..if only i could  use it it's more easier..... but i NEED to use native css