# replacing a whole column in table layout using div

Tags: css, tablelayout

I need to create a display like this using div.

[image]

I HAVE to use div, instead of table because:

1. the content of each cell may be different, yet the height between siblings must be the same.
2. when the red part is clicked, it will replace the whole column

is it even possible?

**UPDATE**

this is my code so far: (it's messy :( )

```
// $data is structured like this:
// $data[0] = ['id' => 101, 'img' => 'img1.jpg', 'username' => 'user1', 'location' => 'mycity1'];
// $data[1] = ['id' => 102, 'img' => 'img2.jpg', 'username' => 'user2', 'location' => 'mycity2'];
// $data[2] = ['id' => 103, 'img' => 'img3.jpg', 'username' => 'user3', 'location' => 'mycity3'];
if (count($data) > 1)
{
    // re-structure $data into $mydata
    // $mydata is structured like this:
    // $mydata['img'] = [ 0 => 'img1.jpg', 1 => 'img2.jpg', 2 => 'img3.jpg' ];
    // $mydata['username'] = [ 0 => 'user1', 1 => 'user2', 2 => 'user3' ];
    // $mydata['location'] = [ 0 => 'mycity1', 1 => 'mycity2', 2 => 'mycity3' ];
    // $mydata['id'] = [ 0 => 101, 1 => 102, 2 => 103 ];
    $mydata = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $val)
    {
        $mydata['img_src'][$key] = $val['img_src'];
        $mydata['username'][$key] = $val['username'];
        $mydata['location'][$key] = $val['location']);
        $mydata['id'][$key] = $val['id'];
    }

    $ndata = count($data);
    $ncol = 4;
    $nrow = ceil($ndata / $ncol);

    $htmlview = '';
    // loop as many rows there would be. e.g. 8 data will create 2 rows
    for ($i=0; $i<$nrow; $i++)
    {
        // each row will contain a table
        $htmlrow = '<table width="100%">';

        // loop each data fields
        foreach ($mydata as $index => $value)
        {
            $htmlrow .= '<tr>'; // each field is displayed in different rows
            $nfield1 = $i * $ncol; // loop index (start)
            $nfield2 = $nfield1 + $ncol; // loop index (end)
            for ($j = $nfield1; $j < $nfield2; $j++) // 0-3; 4-7
            {
                $start = $j == $nfield1;
                $end = $j == $nfield2-1;

                $htmlcontent = '';
                switch ($index)
                {
                    case 'img_src':
                        $htmlcontent = '<img class="suggestuser-img" src="'.$value[$j].'">';
                        break;
                    case 'username':
                        $htmlcontent = '<a href="/user/'.$value[$j].'" class="suggestuser-username default-link wordbreak-all">'
                                            .$value[$j]
                                        .'</a>'
                                        ;
                        break;
                    case 'location':
                        $htmlcontent = '<span class="suggestuser-text wordbreak-all rv-b f3i">'.$value[$j].'</span>';
                        break;
                    case 'id':
                        $htmlcontent = '<button type="button" data-userid="'.$value[$j].'">follow</button>';
                        break;
                }

                $htmlrow .= '<td width="25%" class="suggestuser-col">'
                                .$htmlcontent
                            .'</td>';
            }
            $htmlrow .= '</tr>';
        }
        // end foreach ($mydata as $index => $value)
        $htmlrow .= '</table>';

        if ($i < $nrow)
        {
            // empty line to separate between tables
            $htmlrow .= '<br>';
        }

        $htmlview .= '<div>';
        $htmlview .= $htmlrow;
        $htmlview .= '</div>';
    }
    // end for ($i=0; $i<$nrow; $i++)
}
else // if (count($data) > 1)
{
    $row = $data[0];

    $htmlview = '';
    $htmlview .= '<img class="suggestuser-img" src="'.$row['img_src'].'">'
                .'<a href="/user/'.$row['username'].'" class="suggestuser-username default-link wordbreak-all">'
                    .$row['username']
                .'</a>'
                .'<span class="suggestuser-location wordbreak-all rv-b f3i">'.$row['location'].'</span>'
                .'<button type="button" data-userid="'.$row['id'].'">follow</button>'
                ;
}
// end if (count($data) > 1)
```

so at first, the program calls an ajax request which will display the table part. when one of the button is clicked, the program will make another ajax process which returns the part without table ('else' part). so the stuffs in the corresponding column needs to be replaced with the new data.

sorry I'm not very good at explaining this.

P.S. I didn't include the styles used in this code because they're only for paddings and font-sizes.. and my code is already very messy..

Comment: please share your code so we can help you

Comment: @dapidmini It is possible in table that you want to achieve!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How create table only using <div> tag and Css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css)

Comment: I added my code so far.. please help.. I only managed to use table display right now

Answer (score 0):

since no one seems to have and/or willing to answer this question.. I want to post the workaround I did to solve this problem.

the logic is very simple:

first, when I generated the tables, I gave each item on the same column a unique identifier.

then, I used javascript to change each item having that identifier manually using several `for` loops.

I wanted to put the code here, but it became even messier than the code in the questions..