# Print large table content on multiple page using mpdf lib

Tags: php, yii2, mpf

I need to print a large table content on multiple pages by using mpdf.

action code

```
<?php
.....
 $pdfFile = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(40) . ".pdf";
            $pdf = new Pdf([
                'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
                'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
                'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
                'destination' => Pdf::DEST_FILE,
                'content' => $content,
                'filename' => Helper::UPLOAD_FOLDER . "/" . Helper::REPORT_FOLDER . "/" . $pdfFile,
                'options' => ['title' => $pageTitle],
                'methods' => [
                    'SetHTMLFooter' => [$footerText],
                ]
                ,
            ]);

            $pdf->render();
...
?>
enter code here
```

And this is the view code which is loaded in the pdf

```
<div style="page-break-inside:auto">
<table style="page-break-inside: auto;">
    <tr>
        <td>

       The large content here 

        </td>
    </tr>


</table>

</div>
```

The table content is fit to one page  but I need to be on multiple pages.
[image: problem]

I tested the solution which is mentioned in the link but it dosn't work .

https://mpdf.github.io/tables/tables.html

Comment: @ShashankShah Thank you but I need solution with mpdf lib.

Comment: Have to tried to put your large table content into css ? 
Note:- mPDF doesn't support % but supports px when you try. 

give it a try to set your table's content in proper way ie. (width:100px;)

Comment: @ShashankShah I did that but same result :(

Comment: Please use div table structure so work perfect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css