# How to force child of td in table to use 100% space of td without specifying parent's size?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with a format like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <th> </th>
    <th>foo1</th>
    <th>foo2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Text that makes the cell use two lines of height</th>

        <td className="grid-item">
            <b>P</b>
        </td>

        <td className="grid-item">
            <div>✔ 17/10/2019</div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    /* more tr s */
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and when click a external button, it turns something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <th> </th>
    <th>foo1</th>
    <th>foo2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>
        <th>Text that makes the cell use two lines of height</th>

        <td className="grid-item green_border">
            <div className="clickeable-cpopup">
                <b>P</b>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td className="grid-item green_border">
            <div className="clickeable-cpopup">
                <div>✔ 17/10/2019</div>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    /* more tr s */
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the div "clickeable-cpopup" has a onClick function and it needs to fill all space of its `td` parent, height and width, otherwise i click the `td` instead of the div and nothing happens.

the `"grid-item"` has `padding: 0` and i tried the solution of apply `display: flex` to the `"grid-item"`, it works in filling the space but the table format gets messed up.

Also I tried with better results giving `position: relative` to the `"grid-item"` and `absolute` to both `"clickeable-cpopup"` and `"content"`. The clickeable div use all space in the `td` but then the cell that contains the date doesnt adjust to its content (the width of the cell is smaller that the lengh of the date)

How could I achieve this? I would like to avoid make the td clickeable.

Fixing the cell size is not a good option, a column that only contains `<b>P</b>` should be smaller thant a column that contains both `P` and `date`, an P could become a date and vice versa and some headers of the first column may use 2 lines of height.
And of course neither `width: auto` nor `100%` work since the `"grid-item"` doesn't have a fixed size

Comment: I think better would be to use Div only to create a table. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css

Comment: Not sure where to put this, since is not the answer but by now, I ended up converting the `div "clickeable-cpopup"` into `td` and managing in the map function that constructs the table if the elemen to be inserted is a td, just the element is displayed instead of the element inside a td