# How to split div element into multiple rows and columns in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 images into a div, how to split them in 2 columns of 2 images in CSS?

```
   <div id="your-cards">
    <img src="./cards/BACK5.jpeg" aria-valuetext="7-c" id="P0">
    <img src="./cards/BACK5.jpeg" aria-valuetext="4-c" id="P1">
    <img src="./cards/BACK5.jpeg" aria-valuetext="2-h" id="P2">
    <img src="./cards/BACK5.jpeg" aria-valuetext="A-c" id="P3">
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Use [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How create table only using <div> tag and Css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css)

Comment: the downvoting is because you're not contributing (showing an attempt).

Comment: Also because similar questions are asked and answered many times already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and set the set the [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) to repeat twice with a size that matches the dimensions of the images.

```css
#your-cards { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50px); gap: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<div id="your-cards">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/555/f0f" aria-valuetext="7-c" id="P0">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/6e6/fff" aria-valuetext="4-c" id="P1">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/a33/fff" aria-valuetext="2-h" id="P2">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/44d/fff" aria-valuetext="A-c" id="P3">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use css [`flex` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to do this:

```css
#your-cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#your-cards div {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="your-cards">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

When you give `flex` 3 properties, it specifies:

- [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)
- [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)
- [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

Comment: While Flexbox does work as your example shows, I would not recommend it it. Flexbox' layout is content-driven, but we want to have a rigid and structured layout, so CSS Grid is more preferable.

Comment: @OskarGrosser just wondering how, if a div is specified to have a width of 50%, it would exceed that?

Comment: Without `width: 50%`, your `DIV`s may force the next element onto the next row; with it, its content may overflow onto the next element. Flexbox is designed [for content (or flow)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#overview), whereas Grid is designed [for content _alignment_](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#intro) (or rather, grids).