# if I put a div as a table-cell into a table-column it disappears? taking it out makes it re-appear

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-tables

I have a few super simple divs, one that is a table, another that is a table-column, and another that is a table-cell. putting the cell inside the column makes it dissapear but taking it out makes it re-appear. i am very confused, and I need it to be inside of the column so it is centered.

I have tried deleting the code and re-writing it but that didn't work and yielded the same results. I also looked it up but couldn't find anyone else with the same problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  .guess{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: black;
    display: table-cell;
  }
  .guesses{
    display:table;
  }
  .guesscolumn{
    display:table-column;
  }
</style>
  <div class="guesses">
    <div id="guess1" class="guesscolumn">
      <div class="guess"id="guessbox1:1" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: may be this link is helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053205/how-create-table-only-using-div-tag-and-css

Comment: You are trying to nest a table-cell into a table-column, but that really makes rather little sense. `td` elements do not get nested into `col` elements, when you write a "real" table in HTML - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col